# How do I determine which Jest test is failing to run within the timeout?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm working with dockerised NestJS, and am running tests using Jest (ts-jest). One of my tests is exceeding the timeout of 5000 ms and is causing the entire test suite to fail, however the command line output is very generic (see below).

```
   ● Test suite failed to run
nest-test         |
nest-test         |     Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 50000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 50000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
nest-test         |
nest-test         |       at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:29:45)
```

How can I find out which test is causing the error?

Other online answers online suggest to "just increase the timeout", but all of my tests *should* each run individually within 50 seconds, so I'd prefer to find out which one is failing.

Comment: It says 50 seconds, not 5, so you could start from a block that has custom timeout.

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right - I've edited the post to correct that. However, each test already has a custom timeout of 5000ms (shorter than the Jest timeout of 50000ms), yet they're not being obeyed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add flags: --verbose --runInBand to see the test case failures.

Using --inspect-brk to debug the test case for more detail.